# React - onClick returns 'null undefined' when Clicking on <li>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I've created a list of images in React. I have the name of each image displayed on the screen, and I want the URL to be saved in state, when someone clicks on the name of the image.

When I click on one of the image names, I get `null undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react'

const images = [
    { name: 'Image 1', url: 'https://some.com' },
    { name: 'Image 2', url: 'https://thing.com' }
]

class Imglist extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            url: null
        }
    }

    onClick(event) {
        this.setState(event.value)
        return console.log(this.state.url, event.value)
    }

    render() {

        var that = this

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {images.map(function(element, index) {
                       return <li key={index} onClick={that.onClick.bind(that)}>{element.name}</li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Imglist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'

const images = [
    { name: 'Image 1', url: 'https://some.com' },
    { name: 'Image 2', url: 'https://thing.com' }
]

class Imglist extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            url: null
        }

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this); // <-- bind early
    }

    onClick(element) {
        // setState is async, so your code does not work. to make it works, add your console log in a callback.

        this.setState({url: element.url}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.url, event.value)
         })
    }

    render() {

        var that = this

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {images.map(function(element, index) { // <-- you can use arrow func, so that you don't need to assign this to that.
                       return <li key={index} onClick={() => that.onClick(element)}>{element.name}</li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Imglist
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onClick` function should be

```
onClick(url) {
  this.setState({url}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.url, url)
   })
}
```

No need `return` a `console`, and this.setState is an `async` function, you should use a callback to get the right value. And use `arrow function` when `map`

```
// JSX
{images.map(({name, url}, index) => {
   return <li key={index} onClick={() => this.onClick(url)}>{name}</li>
 })}
```

Comment: Copy pasted your code in, and I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: `event.target.value` this is valid only for <input.../>

Comment: I still get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` :(

Comment: @Leu ops. I missed it was a `li` tag.

Comment: Leu - I thought that might be the case. Is there a way I can yank the <li> value and put it into state onClick, or do I need to use a different tag?

Answer (score 1):

event.target.value is used to retrieve form value, not a click event.

Try this:

```
 <ul>
     {images.map(function(element, index) {
       return <li key={index} onClick={e => this.onClick(element)}>{element.name}</li>
     })}
</ul>
```

and your `onClick` should be

```
onClick(element) {
  this.setState({url: element.url}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.url, event.target.value)
   })
}
```

Comment: When I use your code I get `Line 43:  'onClick' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: should be this.onClick

Comment: And now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClick' of undefined`